# apache poi error zip file is closed

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to open an excel `.xlsx` file using the apache poi libs but am encountering the error below.

Here's the code for the part where the error is occurring. The `xlsx` file is stored in res/raw. What's happening here that is causing the error?

```
            String folderdir = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.register_template;
//Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(folderdir));
        OPCPackage xlsx = OPCPackage.open(new File(folderdir));//must be .xlsx file type
        XSSFWorkbook xlsxwb = new XSSFWorkbook(xlsx);

        xlsx.save(jobno_file);
        xlsx.close();
```

**Error code :**

```
   09-20 16:12:07.039    5694-5694/ E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: , PID: 5694
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Zip File is closed
            at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipFileZipEntrySource.getEntries(ZipFileZipEntrySource.java:45)
            at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.getPartsImpl(ZipPackage.java:182)
            at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.getParts(OPCPackage.java:665)
            at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:253)
            at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:200)
            at au.com.prensa.prensa.generalinfo.save_register(generalinfo.java:83)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell exactly where this goes wrong. You cannot use File on such a path as it is not a path to a file on the file system. If the unzipper cannot be invoked by offering an InputStream then you have to copy the 'file' from res/raw to the file system first.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
instead of using `File`, use `InputStream`.
For example:

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new ClassPathResource("/apiLogDtlsReport.xlsx").getInputStream());
```